# Why is Micrometer MeterRegistryCustomizer deny not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer, jaeger, spring-micrometer

I am using `Kotlin` with spring boot version 3.0.4 alongside with micrometer to send some tracing to `Jaeger`. But since I deployed this app into a `Kubernetes` instance it keeps checking the URL/actuator/healthy, but I do not want those calls to be sent to `Jaeger`.

I am trying to use `MeterRegistryCustomizer` deny, to keep those calls from being sent to `Jaeger`, but it seems that deny is not working, even when I set it to deny everything.
I am gonna paste the bean I am using to exclude those calls, which is not working at the moment.

**The Code:**

```
@Bean
fun buildMeterRegistry(): MeterRegistryCustomizer < MeterRegistry > {
  return MeterRegistryCustomizer < MeterRegistry > {
    registry ->
    registry.config()
    .meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny())
    .meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny {
      id ->
        val uri: String ? = id.getTag("uri")
        (uri != null &&
          (uri.startsWith("/actuator") ||
            uri.startsWith("/metrics") ||
            uri.startsWith("/health") ||
            uri.startsWith("/favicon.ico") ||
            uri.startsWith("/prometheus")))
    })
  }
}
```

It seems that deny is not working because even when I set it up like this, it keeps sending all the metrics to `Jaeger`.

**The Code:**

```
@Bean
fun buildMeterRegistry(): MeterRegistryCustomizer < MeterRegistry > {
  return MeterRegistryCustomizer < MeterRegistry > {
    registry ->
    registry.config()
    .meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny())
    .meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny {
      true
    })
  }
}
```

**Also tried (as suggested):**

```
@Bean
fun meterFilter(): MeterFilter {
    return object : MeterFilter {
        override fun accept(id: Meter.Id): MeterFilterReply {
            return MeterFilterReply.DENY
        }
    }
}
```

So I'd like your help to understand how I could keep/deny some requests from being published to my Jaeger instance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @AztecCodes, I've updated my question by changing a few bits, even though, it did not change that much, would you mind telling me what's wrong with my question? Since I've read the guidelines I think I've supplied enough info about what the problem is and how to reproduce it. Thanks

Comment: Adding at least the Boot version could help.
Could you please try to create a `MeterFilter` `@Bean`? Boot should auto-configure it.

Comment: hey @JonatanIvanov thanks for your answer, I tried your suggestion but that did not work out. I've added the snippet to my question.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you are way off. Micrometer is for metrics, MeterFilter filters Meters not Spans. If you want to filter Spans, you need to use an ObservationFilter or a SpanFilter.